# How to use a method to return as a label of the view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have set a field and a button at the ViewController and at the DetailViewController, I have a label set to receive a string of "A" if the number is less than 10 or "B" if its above 10. However, im unsure how can I access it to show the result. What I have so far:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ResultViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    ResultViewController *resultController = (ResultViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    resultController.segueLabel = self.fieldLabel.text;

}

- (NSString *)number:(int)value {
    int intVal = [[self.fieldLabel text] intValue];
    if (intVal < 10) {
        return @"a";
    }
        else {
            return @"b";
        }
}

- (IBAction)showResultView:(id)sender {
}

@end
```

Comment: Can't tell what you're asking, because I don't see you _doing_ anything with your `number:` method. Who did you want to send this information to?

Comment: @matt i want to use this method to show the @"a" or @"b" as the label at the next view. Currently the label is receiving the text inserted ate the field at self.fieldLabel.text, but i dont want the info from the field, i need the result of the method number that will receive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your `number` method called, then call it! Instead of

```
resultController.segueLabel = self.fieldLabel.text;
```

it sounds like you want to say

```
resultController.segueLabel = [self number:0];
```